# Distinguishing multiline strings that need indentation from those that do not

Tags: perl, emacs, indentation, multilinestring, cperl-mode

**---+ BRIEF**

This question is about indenting multiline strings, e.g. for Perl, in emacs' cperl-mode, so that they do not break up the flow of the code.

I know how to get the indentation I want, using transformations like `=~ s/^[^\S\n]*\|//mhr` on the string, and providing emacs :about advice to `cperl-calculate-indent`, using `syntax-ppss` to recognize when I am in a string.

Trouble is, sometimes I want to do such indentation, and sometimes not.

What I seek advice about conventions, BKMs, for hinting what the desired indentation is.

```
    my $legacy = qw{
This string
   should
not be indented};

my $needs_trimming = (q{
                          |BEGIN
                          |    SUB
                          |END
                      } =~ s/^[^\S\n]*\|//mgr); 

my $needs_different_triming  = (q{   + - 
                                     , ? : 
                                     | & ^
                                     || && 
                                | =~ s/\s+/ /gr);
```

I expect others have solved this problem before me.

**---+ DETAIL:**

I ask this as an emacs/cperl-mode question, but the problem is generic to languages that allow multiline strings.  Not just Perl, but also Javascript, C/C++,  Javascript ([Multiline strings that don't break indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924057/multiline-strings-that-dont-break-indentation)), LISP and elisp, etc.

I often write Perl code that uses multiline strings.

I dislike how multiline strings break indentation:

```
  if(cond) {
      my $var = q{
START Line crossing string needs
    to be indented
    differently than rest of code
FINISH
};
      my $var2 = ...
  }
```

I prefer to keep the same indentation, so I often do things like

```
   if(cond) {
      my $var = (q{
                  |START Line crossing string needs
                  |     to be indented
                  |     differently than rest of code
                  |FINISH
               } =~ s/^[^\S\n]*\|//mgr);
      my $var2 = ...
   }

   if(cond) {
      my $var = fix_string( {unindent=>'|',trim=>1,}, 
                  q{
                    |START Line crossing string needs
                    |     to be indented
                    |     differently than rest of code
                    |FINISH
                  } =~ s/^[^\S\n]*\|//mgr);
      my $var2 = ...
   }
```

OK, so this works fine, and I have been doing it for years, possibly decades.

What did not work so well in the past was indentation, using packages like `perl-mode' and`cperl-mode'.

OK, so I fixed that, using

```
(defun cperl-calculate-indent--hack--/ag (orig-fun &rest args)
  "hack / experimenting with cperl-calculate-indent"
  (interactive)
  (let ((state (syntax-ppss)))
    (cond
      ((and (nth 3 state)                  ;in string
     (nth 8 state)                     ; beginning of string
     (< (nth 8 state) (point-at-bol))  ; on different line
     )
    (save-excursion
      (goto-start-of-string--ag)
      (+ 4 (current-column)))
    )
      (t (apply orig-fun args))
      )
    )
  )

(advice-add 'cperl-calculate-indent :around #'cperl-calculate-indent--hack--/ag)
;;(advice-remove 'cperl-calculate-indent #'cperl-calculate-indent--hack--/ag)
```

So now I can indent multiline strings.  If that is what I want to do.

Unfortunately, sometimes I do want to indent the multiline string.  And sometimes I don't.

- E.g. I may inherit legacy code that I do not want to accidentally
  break if I edit it in cperl-mode.
- Furthermore, there are different types of indentation / transformations that I may do to such multiline strings:

  1. None - standard cperl-mode indentation for multiline strings
  2. Trim prefix at beginning of line, e.g s/^[\S\n]*
  3. Sometimes I want the same sort of indentation that cperl-mode gives
     to qw{} - basically, I create my own qw that allows things like
     commas without warnings, s/\s+/ /g
  4. Sometimes I may actually want the string to be indented like HTML,
     or C, or ...

I know how to do each of these.  I can cons up a recognizer for any convention.

But... I am looking for suggestions, ideally standard practices or BKMs, as to how to make this distinction. Something that others will find readable.

E.g. I considered creating my own operators using `PerlX::QuoteOperator my_q`.   But that is non-standard, may confuse others, and may break in future. Besides, what I really want to do is just provide an indentation hint, not change the language.

E.g. as explained above, I already use fixup functions
`fixup_string( q{ ... } )`. I could pattern match on these. But this breaks when the user adds new fixup functions, etc.

E.g. I have considered looking at the first line of the string, e.g.

```
fixup_string( q{:
                 :not indented 
                 :     indented
              } )
```

This works for my prefix s/^[^\S\n]*://mgr, but not in other cases.

(I am currently doing `(looking-at ".[~!@#$%^&*_+=|:;'?/]$"))`, which is easy enough, but which has obvious problems (like, what if I want to a string to start `"|\n..."`.  I.e. it fails the test "don't break reasonably likely existing code".)

If Perl had a comment that was NOT to end of line, like C's `/*...*/'I might dp

```
fixup_string( q/*indent-here*/{|
                 | 
                 |
              } )
```

but Perl does have such non-end-of-line comments.  (Does it?  Is there any syntactic trick that is the equivalent?)

Therefore my question.

I am sure that others have solved this problem before.  I would love to know what they did.

---

In many ways this is just a special case of multiple modes inside the same buffer, https://emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes.  I would like to avoid the
problems mentioned in https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HtmlModeDeluxe.

Comment: I don't understand your `s/^[\S\n]*|//mgr`. That will delete all non-space characters and newlines from the beginning of each line in the string, and the `|` will make no difference because it is a regex metacharacter. I would have thought you wanted `s/^\s*\|//mgr`, but you say *"this works fine, and I have been doing it for years, possibly decades"* so you should know.

Comment: Sorry. S/^[^\S\n]*\|//Mgr.  That is what I get for making an edit instead of pasting code in use. And this what I get for using an iPhone. Will fix when I get back to a real keyboard.

Comment: That makes more sense!

Comment: Fixed bug pointed out by @Borodin, `s/^[\S\n]*|//mgr1 --should-be--> `s/^[^\S\n]*\|//mgr`.   Also a similar bug with `s/\s*/ /gr` --should-be--> `s/\s+/ /gr`.

Comment: BTW, I tend to do `[^\S\n]*` rather than `\s*`, to minimize changes needed if I switch from `s///mgr` to `s///gr`.    I have been doing this long enough that I seem to remember when `[^\S\n]` was not allowed inside `[ ]`, but had to enter `[ \t]` - I think long enough that you weren't even allowed `\t` inside `[ ]`, and had to actually provide a not-very-visible tab character.

Comment: Interesting cases, but sometimes less is more... Maybe re-start with a single question?